# qemu kvm VM needs to access Internet by bridging wifi

Tags: linux, wifi, kvm, qemu, bridge

I have some Qemu KVM virtual machines (CentOSs and Debians mostly) and my host is an Ubuntu. I configured the VMs networks with virtio virbr0, and I also made it work by creating a virtual interface, connecting the VMs to that virtual interface (dolling out IPs with dnsmasq) and NATing traffic through the host.

Now, for the purposing of learning, I really wanted to create a bridge, add my wifi interface as one of the ports and connect my VMs into the bridge, but I wasn't successful. As the guy referred above, I also used Debian's [bridge tutorial](https://wiki.debian.org/BridgeNetworkConnections#Bridging_with_a_wireless_NIC) to try to make ebtables "masquerade" my VM MAC address (as the AP won't accept a different MAC from the one that previously authenticated). But my problem is that I couldn't even add my wifi as the bridge port.

my /etc/network/interfaces:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# this is my wifi card (god knows why udev gave this name)
auto wlx44334c371663
iface wlx44334c371663 inet manual

# of course I added my wifi real MAC in bridge_hw option
auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp
        pre-up iwconfig wlx44334c371663 essid myESSID
        bridge_hw 11:11:11:11:11:11
        bridge_ports wlx44334c371663
        bridge_stp off
        bridge_waitport 0
        bridge_fd 0
        bridge_maxwait 0
```

When I start it:

```
$ sudo ifup br0

Waiting for a max of 0 seconds for wlx44334c371663 to become available.
can't add wlx44334c371663 to bridge br0: Operation not supported
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.3.3
Copyright 2004-2015 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

Listening on LPF/br0/11:11:11:11:11:11
Sending on   LPF/br0/11:11:11:11:11:11
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0xe1868a4f)
DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8 (xid=0xe1868a4f)
DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8 (xid=0xe1868a4f)
...
```

Notice up there:

> can't add wlx44334c371663 to bridge br0: Operation not supported

Of course, when I check the bridges, my wifi is not one interface of br0:

```
$ brctl show
bridge name bridge id           STP enabled interfaces
br0         8000.44334c371663   no
virbr0      8000.000000000000   yes
```

It doesn't seem to matter if my wifi is up or down when I start br0, it just won't add it as one interface

The same happens if I try to add my wifi using brctl:

```
$ sudo brctl addif br0 wlx44334c371663
can't add wlx44334c371663 to bridge br0: Operation not supported
```

PS.: this is an external wifi device (rt2800usb), I also have the laptop onboard wifi (ath10k_pci) and neither seem to work. The ethernet works though (but I have no ethernet cable where I am). So, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: When using a configurable hostapd on the AP, it's possible to set the hostapd to accept both normal Wifi frames with 3 MAC addresses and Wifi frames in 4addr mode: hostapd can then automatically and dynamically create an additional 4addr mode interface for each such client (most certainly using wpa_supplicant with adequate configuration) while continuing to serve normal clients. In 4addr mode communication, bridging is allowed on the client (as well as on the AP as usual). As this depends on the AP, I'm just leaving a comment.